# Applying if else statements involving two dataframe columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, sapply

I am trying to modify a dataframe of two columns, to add a third that returns four possible expressions depending on the contents of the other columns (i.e. whether each is positive or negative).

I have tried a couple of approaches, the 'mutate' function in dplyr as well as sapply. Unfortunately I seem to be missing something as I get the error "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". So only the first iteration is applied to each row in the new column.

A reproducible example (of the mutate approach I've tried) is as follows:

```
Costs <- c(2, -5, -7, 3, 12)
Outcomes <- c(-2, 5, -7, 3, -2)

results <- as.data.frame(cbind(Costs, Outcomes))
results

quadrant <- function(cost,outcome) {
        if (costs < 0 &
            outcomes < 0) {
                "SW Quadrant"
        }
        else if (costs<0 & outcomes>0){
                "Dominant"
        } 
        else if (costs>0 & outcomes<0){
                "Dominated"
        }
        else{""}
}


results <- mutate(results,Quadrant = quadrant(Costs,Outcomes)
        )
```

The full warning message is:

> Warning messages:
> 1: Problem with `mutate()` input `Quadrant`.
> i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> i Input `Quadrant` is `quadrant(results$Costs, results$Outcomes)`.
> 2: In if (costs < 0 & outcomes < 0) { :
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> 3: Problem with `mutate()` input `Quadrant`.
> i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> i Input `Quadrant` is `quadrant(results$Costs, results$Outcomes)`.
> 4: In if (costs < 0 & outcomes > 0) { :
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> 5: Problem with `mutate()` input `Quadrant`.
> i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> i Input `Quadrant` is `quadrant(results$Costs, results$Outcomes)`.
> 6: In if (costs > 0 & outcomes < 0) { :
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used<

My attempt at the sapply function:

```
results <- sapply(results$Quadrant,quadrant(results$Costs,results$Outcomes))
```

Leads to the following error, with consistent warning messages to the mutate approach.

> Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :
> object 'Dominated' of mode 'function' was not found

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: I added an answer below, but I think the main problem is that `if()` isn't vectorized, so the evaluation happens on the first element, not element-wise like the `ifelse()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going wrong with that function.

1. You define the function with `cost` but use `costs` (same for outcome);
2. You use `if` which strictly requires a logical condition of length 1, and two things wrong: you use `&` which should almost never be used exposed like this in an `if` statement, *and* you are passing vectors, so `cost < 0` will return a logical vector the same length of `cost` (which is greater than 1 here).

Suggestions:

```r
quadrant_sgl <- function(cost, outcome) {
  if (cost < 0 && outcome < 0) return("SW Quadrant")
  if (cost < 0 && outcome > 0) return("Dominant")
  if (cost > 0 && outcome < 0) return("Dominated")
  return("")
}

quadrant_vec1 <- function(cost, outcome) {
  ifelse(cost < 0 & outcome < 0, "SW Quadrant",
         ifelse(cost < 0 & outcome > 0, "Dominant",
                ifelse(cost > 0 & outcome < 0, "Dominated",
                       "")))
}

quadrant_vec2 <- function(cost, outcome) {
  ifelse(cost < 0,
         ifelse(outcome < 0, "SW Quadrant", "Dominant"),
         ifelse(outcome < 0, "Dominated", ""))
}

quadrant_vec3 <- function(cost, outcome) {
  dplyr::case_when(
    cost < 0 & outcome < 0 ~ "SW Quadrant",
    cost < 0 & outcome > 0 ~ "Dominant",
    cost > 0 & outcome < 0 ~ "Dominated",
    TRUE ~ ""
  )
}

quadrant_vec4 <- function(cost, outcome) {
  data.table::fcase(
    cost < 0 & outcome < 0, "SW Quadrant",
    cost < 0 & outcome > 0, "Dominant",
    cost > 0 & outcome < 0, "Dominated",
    rep(TRUE, length(cost)), ""
  )
}
```

The first function (`quadrant_sgl`) turns a function that remains single-operation (not vectorized) into a vectorized function. If you aren't familiar with the concept of vectorization, know that (1) R does it well, (2) R prefers it, and (3) this is not the best venue to talk at length about this. Search for "R vectorization" and you should find plenty of material on this.

Because of this, the first one is just a demonstration of what to do when the function cannot (due to time, programming skill, or something else) be converted into a vectorize-friendly function. Use `Vectorize`.

The other functions are all relatively equivalent.

If you are using `dplyr` and friends, then I strongly recommend the use of `quadrant_vec3`, since it is (IMO) much easier to read and maintain than nested `ifelse`s. (BTW: if you must use nested `ifelse`, then at least use `dplyr::if_else`s, nested, as they are generally safer than base R's `ifelse`.)

If you are venturing into the world of `data.table`, then `quadrant_vec4` is the equivalent using `data.table`'s own `fcase` function, mostly the same as `case_when`.

Demo:

```r
Vectorize(quadrant_sgl, vectorize.args = c("cost", "outcome"))(results$Costs, results$Outcomes)
# [1] "Dominated"   "Dominant"    "SW Quadrant" ""            "Dominated"  
quadrant_vec1(results$Costs, results$Outcomes)
# [1] "Dominated"   "Dominant"    "SW Quadrant" ""            "Dominated"  
quadrant_vec2(results$Costs, results$Outcomes)
# [1] "Dominated"   "Dominant"    "SW Quadrant" ""            "Dominated"  
quadrant_vec3(results$Costs, results$Outcomes)
# [1] "Dominated"   "Dominant"    "SW Quadrant" ""            "Dominated"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and apologies for the typo with costs/cost, long day yesterday). I've found the multiple different examples and explanation really helpful to get my head around vectorisation. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something more like:

```
costs <- c(2, -5, -7, 3, 12)
outcomes <- c(-2, 5, -7, 3, -2)

results <- as.data.frame(cbind(costs, outcomes))

results <- results %>% mutate(Quadrant = case_when(
  outcomes < 0 & costs < 0 ~ "SW Quadrant", 
  costs < 0 & outcomes > 0 ~ "Dominant", 
  costs > 0 & outcomes < 0 ~ "Dominated", 
  TRUE ~ ""))

results
#   costs outcomes    Quadrant
# 1     2       -2   Dominated
# 2    -5        5    Dominant
# 3    -7       -7 SW Quadrant
# 4     3        3            
# 5    12       -2   Dominated
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly well and I hadn't heard about case_when previously. Much appreciated!